# Extract data from R and paste them in a new data frame with a different format

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a large with several plant species and several locations set where always three columns belong to one location, giving in the first column the presence of a species (1 = present, empty = not present), in the second column the altitude where the species was found and in the third column a note (see below).

```
Location         A          A         A         B            B        B
Index         Presence    Altitude    Note    Presence    Altitude    Note
Species A                                       1          2560    Something
Species B        1        3100       Some
Species C
Species D        1        2899       Some
```

Now I want to extract all species that occur at one location (where Presence = 1) and post them into a new data frame in the following format:

```
Location         Species         Altitude       Note
   A                B              3100         Some
   A                D              2899         Some
   B                A              2560         Something
```

I have tried several things but nothing worked not even closely. I appreciate every input. Thank you.

Added: I uploaded an example of how the data looks [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgKLX-FSdg9db4q3XLzz1IGCbxs)

Comment: The format of original data is not apparent. Is it already a `data.frame` in R? In that case printing out a few line using `dput` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data frame of the following form:

```
dat <- structure(list(Loc_Index = c("Species A", "Species B", "Species C", 
 "Species D"), A.Presence = c("", "1", "", "1"), A.Altitude = c("", 
 "3100", "", "2899"), A.Note = c("", "Some", "", "Some"), B.Presence = c("1", 
 "", "", ""), B.Altitude = c("2560", "", "", ""), B.Note = c("Something", 
 "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Species", "A.Presence", 
 "A.Altitude", "A.Note", "B.Presence", "B.Altitude", "B.Note"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> dat
#     Species A.Presence A.Altitude A.Note B.Presence B.Altitude    B.Note
# 1 Species A                                       1       2560 Something
# 2 Species B          1       3100   Some                                
# 3 Species C                                                             
# 4 Species D          1       2899   Some
```

You could achieve that using a combination of `tidyr` gathers and spreads and some `dplyr` manipulation:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat2 <- dat %>% tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, A.Presence, 
                A.Altitude, A.Note, B.Presence, B.Altitude, B.Note) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(Location = substr(key, 1, 1), 
                parameter = sub("^.*\\.", "", key),
                Species = sub("^.*\\s", "", Species)) %>%
        dplyr::select(Location, Species, parameter, value) %>%
        tidyr::spread(key = parameter, value = value) %>%
        dplyr::filter(Presence == 1) %>% select(-Presence)

> dat2
#   Location Species Altitude      Note
# 1        A       B     3100      Some
# 2        A       D     2899      Some
# 3        B       A     2560 Something
```